# Oracle VM issue + Ubuntu is not starting

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have this Virtual Machine issue when installing Ubuntu.I have done a huge search to overcome this but I failed.So please help me out.

I'm using Oracle VM (Virtual Box) **4.2.14** and I have installed it on **Windows 8 (64 bit)**.
Following are the settings.

[image]

And when I start Ubuntu, I get the starting screen and screen gets **freezes**.
[image]
[image]

Why and how can I start Ubuntu ? Please help me out

Comment: @Jobin: with virtualbox the issues and solutions may be different.

Comment: Please also upgrade your Virtual Box for bugfixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience that usually means a damaged virtual disk, but in your case it could also be settings related. I noticed your settings don't list anything under acceleration. It would also be helpful if you mentioned whether this was a pre-built machine, or if you installed Ubuntu yourself.

Screenshot of VirtualBox 4.3.6 Default Unaltered Settings For Ubuntu VMs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylumP.png