# Oracle VM - Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, oracle

I recently updated my VirtualBox after not using it for about half a year (Newest version - 5.0.22 r108108). I have a 200GB VM running Ubuntu 64-bit (I can't remember what version exactly) and now simply tried to start it again in VirtualBox.

**Having one issue fixed** which solution is probably wrong, but I did not seem to get any other way from Google to work
(My virtualisation *is* and was always *enabled* in BIOS settings)

- VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

by manually editing the *.vbox file and setting these values from true to false:

```
<HardwareVirtEx enabled="false"/>
<HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="false"/>
<HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="false"/>
```

**a second issue** pops up, or rather - was unnoticed there all the time.

Suddenly it seems that ALL 64-bit versions are gone from the combobox[es] when trying to create a new virtual machine.

I have the **VM image** plus old backups, and I can't add a new 64-bit machine with this existing VM image. I'm done with trying to find an answer through Google and found here only a [few hints](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440598/oracle-vm-issue-ubuntu-is-not-starting) which don't seem to help. Also under the "System" settings of the VM, it decided to set itself to 1 core, which was previously set on 4. This slider appears to be disabled.

Additional info:
I have a 64-bit Windows 10 VM running smoothly.
My computer meets the requirements [specified here.](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/how_to_configure_a_64)

> If you do not see the 64-bit options in the drop-down list then VirtualBox thinks that your machine has not met the pre-requisites above.

I am not quite sure why VirtualBox has now decided that my system suddenly doesn't meet the requirements anymore - no hardware changes.

**Does anyone know a solution or a few hints in order to solve this problem ?**

Comment: Update - Now my Windows 10 VM doesn't start anymore too. The virtualisation error pops up. Editing the file manually does not help.